SendTransactionError: Simulation failed
I am trying to update metadata for my coin but after running my ts file (below) I get the following error. I have all the dependencies. I also have enough Sol in my wallet. Not sure what's causing this. Any assistance would be appreciated.
SendTransactionError: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete.
Logs:
[
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]",
  "Program log: IX: Create Metadata Accounts v3",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token/utils.rs:50:27",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 11228 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: SBF program panicked"
].
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\bumbo\OneDrive\Desktop\DaMorDiKos\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:6043:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\bumbo\OneDrive\Desktop\DaMorDiKos\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5999:20)
    at async Object.sendTransaction (C:\Users\bumbo\OneDrive\Desktop\DaMorDiKos\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-rpc-web3js\src\createWeb3JsRpc.ts:327:25)       
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (C:\Users\bumbo\OneDrive\Desktop\DaMorDiKos\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi\src\TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)    
    at async main (C:\Users\bumbo\OneDrive\Desktop\DaMorDiKos\deploy-token.ts:49:22) {
  signature: '',
  transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: IX: Create Metadata Accounts v3',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token/utils.rs:50:27",
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 11228 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: SBF program panicked'

This is my ts file:
import {Collection, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs, Creator, MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID, UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts, UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData, Uses, createMetadataAccountV3, updateMetadataAccountV2, findMetadataPda} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { PublicKey, createSignerFromKeypair, none, signerIdentity, some } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { fromWeb3JsKeypair, fromWeb3JsPublicKey} from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters';

export function loadWalletKey(keypairFile:string): web3.Keypair {
    const fs = require("fs");
    const loaded = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
      new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairFile).toString())),
    );
    return loaded;
  }

const INITIALIZE = true;

async function main(){
    console.log("let's name some tokens in 2024!");
    const myKeypair = loadWalletKey("meowpgTrtqhzCzGzv86iX3NQ2.json");
    const mint = new web3.PublicKey("5JYoErVM3f2uVrcXdjjLvRWPsBdGuW7Hv9M8BKTa23c5");

    const umi = createUmi("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
    const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, fromWeb3JsKeypair(myKeypair))
    umi.use(signerIdentity(signer, true))

    const ourMetadata = { // TODO change those values!
        "name": "MEOW-WOOF",
        "symbol": "MEOF",
        uri: "https://pink-neighbouring-mite-14.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmPUCjQgpMkn538Ne2yPmDwrFmrxvnvMVHcENVLJ61B3Go",
    }
    const onChainData = {
        ...ourMetadata,
        // we don't need that
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        creators: none<Creator[]>(),
        collection: none<Collection>(),
        uses: none<Uses>(),
    }
    if(INITIALIZE){
        const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
            mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
            mintAuthority: signer,
        }
        const data: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs = {
            isMutable: true,
            collectionDetails: null,
            data: onChainData
        }
        const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {...accounts, ...data}).sendAndConfirm(umi);
        console.log(txid)
    } else {
        const data: UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData = {
            data: some(onChainData),
            discriminator: 0,
            isMutable: some(true),
            newUpdateAuthority: none<PublicKey>(),
            primarySaleHappened: none<boolean>()
        }
        const accounts: UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts = {
            metadata: findMetadataPda(umi,{mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint)}),
            updateAuthority: signer
        }
        const txid = await updateMetadataAccountV2(umi, {...accounts, ...data} ).sendAndConfirm(umi);
        console.log(txid)
    }

}

main();


Came across this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77724505/error-during-metadata-creation-send-transaction-error-failed-to-send-transacti wonderng if that's the answer. I tried with no luck.

Most likely you are trying to call two tx's

mint tx
add metadata tx

after each other and the error occurs because the add metadata tx is trying to read the mint account when it hasn't been properly propagated to other nodes that the account exists.
A solution to this would be to add a sleep function between the two function calls.

// --- snip imports

async function createToken() {
    let tx = await createMint(umi, {
        mint,
        decimals: 6,
        mintAuthority: umi.identity.publicKey,
        freezeAuthority: null,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    let txSig = base58.deserialize(tx.signature);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSig}?cluster=devnet`);
}

// Metadata for the Token
const tokenMetadata = {
    name: "Solana Gold",
    symbol: "GOLDSOL",
    uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
};

async function addMetadata() {
    const metadataAccountAddress = await findMetadataPda(umi, {
        mint: mint.publicKey,
    });

    const tx = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {
        metadata: metadataAccountAddress,
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: umi.identity,
        payer: umi.identity,
        updateAuthority: umi.identity,
        data: {
            creators: null,
            name: tokenMetadata.name,
            symbol: tokenMetadata.symbol,
            uri: tokenMetadata.uri,
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            collection: null,
            uses: null,
        },
        collectionDetails: null,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    let txSig = base58.deserialize(tx.signature);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSig}?cluster=devnet`);
}

async function createTokenAndAddMD() {
    console.log("calling mint");
    await createToken();

    await sleep(20000); // wait before adding the metadata

    console.log("calling add MD");
    await addMetadata();
}

createTokenAndAddMD().then().catch(console.error);


Thanks. I will test the given code. What I don't understand is how come the mint wasn't properly initialized? I primarily used CLI for mint creation but it seems like the mint account wasn't registered on the network. Solscan does show supply and creation but not sure it could fail

that's strange. What about other explorers apart from solscan.

All shows same informations. I am thinking to recreate a new test token (though I did the same) and this time confirm the mint and see. One more thing I am running tsx followed by the t's file tsx xxxx.ts - this won't make a difference right.

Update: I created another token and initialized it's mint. Explorer shows all previous activities as they were done using CLI. Same error.
